# Why do I get a Graph when I specify create_using=nx.DiGraph

Tags: python, pandas, networkx

I'm new to networkx in python and I had a problem in creating a DiGraph. I specify `create_using=nx.DiGraph` when I try to create a DiGraph using the adjacency matrix in pd dataframe, but I got a Graph instead of a DiGraph. Can anyone explain why?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

This is apparently a bug, that is fixed in the new version of `networkx`. The problem is on [this line](https://github.com/networkx/networkx/blob/242ca83f1216080449be506cea7c9b14223b6d68/networkx/convert_matrix.py#L1910).

You can either install the new version of `networkx` to fix it, or implement the solution yourself (you need just to add a word). If you chose the second, open the file `networkx.convert_matrix.py`, which in my system is found at: `/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/networkx/convert_matrix.py` (open the file as root using sudo), and change line 191 from:

```
G = from_numpy_matrix(A, create_using)
```

to

```
G = from_numpy_matrix(A, create_using=create_using)
```

And listo, bug should be solved. Note: is `create_using=nx.DiGraph()`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But here I used from_pandas_adjacency why I need to change function about from_numpy_matrix?

Comment: And I updated my networks to the latest version. It still doesn't work.

Comment: @Jie That code I wrote is on the function `from_pandas_adjacency`. After fixing that line the code works. By getting the final version I mean changing to the version on github by cloning the repository. I think is best if you follow my advice and change the line I told you about.

Comment: Hi I find the file but the 191 line is not the one you said and I didn't find from_pandas_adjacency in the file, I only find from_pandas_dataframe

Comment: Hi, I find the 191 line the same as you said in another convert_matrix.py.(I don't know why I have 2 files named  convert_matrix.py). And I changed it as you said but it still not works......

Comment: @Jie That's because you have two versions of python. What is the path to these files?